# if an element is found in a selector, why can't I add a classname in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, jquery-mobile

I'm pretty lost on this one...

I have a container with three panels and I need to add a class to all of them. If I do a selector like so:

```
   $('#container').find('div:jqmData(role="panel")').length;
```

Firebug tells me, it's three panels, although when I hover over the source code, one panel is not highlighted and has a height of 0.

If I do this in the following line:

```
   $('#container').find('div:jqmData(role="panel")').addClass("HELLO");
```

this element, albeit found, does not get the class "HELLO". The other two element get a class of "HELLO"

I'm wondering for a while now how this can be, because the console is right before the addClass, so if there are three elements found, why do only two elements get "HELLO"? Also, the height of an element should be irrelevant when assigning a class, shouldn't it?

I have W3C-ed the source. All ok. This is the brief version:

```
<div data-role="page" id="container">
    // one
    <div data-role="panel" data-panel="menu">
        <div data-role="page" id="menu_first">                                
               <p>Menu Lorem Ipsum</p>                              
        </div>       
    </div>
    // two
    <div data-role="panel" data-panel="mid">
        <div data-role="page" id="mid_first">                
             <p>Mid Lorem Ipsum</p>                             
        </div>       
    </div>
    // three
     <div data-role="panel" data-panel="main">
        <div data-role="page" id="main_first">                
             <p>Main Lorem Ipsum</p>                             
        </div>       
    </div>
</div>
```

The jquery is in a long plugin. These are the relevant parts:

```
(function( $, window) {     
$.widget("mobile.multiview",$.mobile.widget, {

       _create: function() {
            var self = this;
            self._mainEventBindings();
            },
       _mainEventBindings: function () {
            $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', 'div:jqmData(role="page")', function(event, data){
               var page = $(this);
               if ( page.data("counter") == 0 || typeof page.data("counter") == 'undefined') {
                   self.setupMultiview(event, page);
                   }
            });
          },
       setupMultiview: function(event, page) {
            var self = this;
            page.find("div:jqmData(role='panel')").addClass('HELLO').end()  
            } 
       }) (jQuery,this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Found a

```
 $('div:jqmData(panel="mid")').removeClass()
```

which cleared everything that had been assigned correctly.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$('div').each( function() {
    if( $(this).data('role') == "panel" ) {
       $this.addClass("HELLO");
    }
});
```

Comment: Not sure but the double quotes might be screwing it up... it should be $this.addClass('HELLO');

Comment: nope. should be ok. I think I found the problem. There was a removeClass() somewhere in the code, which I forgot to delete. This cleared the middle panel of all classes (after they had been assigned correctly). Thanks for your help!